# CodeIgniter db query not working as expected

Tags: php, codeigniter, yii

I am trying to pass parameters from `Yii MVC` to a `CodeIgniter` model method and search for results between a time interval;

The `created` property has values like `26/2/2014`;

Will the `query` execute and concat the two `where` clauses regarding the field `created` with `get_where` clause?

Or it will execute only the `get_where` clause?

I can't see the result, but the `created` value is being passed;

the `created` field is stored as a `timestamp` value in the `db` and I use a `date picker` to select the `day/month/year`, then I pass the value thru the `api` and then I create the `24 hour` time interval

and this is where i got stuck;

ps: this is a good example when using `EActiveResource` instead of `ActiveRecord` and passing data thru a `api` built using `codeIgniter`

```
public function findAll($params) {
        if (!empty($params)) {
            if (isset($params['created'])) {
                $e = explode('/', $params['created']);
                $month = $e[1];
                $day = $e[0];
                $year = $e[2];
                $start = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year);
                $end = mktime(23, 59, 59, $month, $day, $year);
                $this->db->where('created >', $start);
                $this->db->where('created <', $end);
            }
            $query = $this->db->get_where($this->_table, $params);
        } else {
            $query = $this->db->get($this->_table);
        }
        $ret = $query->result_array();
        foreach ($ret as $key => $value) {
            $ret[$key]['order_id'] = $value['id'];
        }
        return (isset($ret) && !empty($ret)) ? $ret : false;
    }
```

I tryed to set the value of `$params['created']` within `yii` and pass it to `codeIgniter` just to make sure I pass the `if`;

In the `codeIgniter` model I have:

```
    if (!empty($params)) {
        if (isset($params['created'])) {
            $this->db->where('created >=', 1393246473);
            $this->db->where('created <=', 1393404935);
        }
        $query = $this->db->get_where($this->_table, $params);
    } else {
        $query = $this->db->get($this->_table);
    }
    $ret = $query->result_array();
```

still no data as result;

any ideas?

Comment: it should concat the `where` and `get_where`.  Do `var_dump($this->db->last_query());` after your `get_where` to see what query was executed and add the result to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public function findAll($params) {
            if (!empty($params)) {
                if (isset($params['created'])) {
                    $e = explode('/', $params['created']);
                    $month = $e[1];
                    $day = $e[0];
                    $year = $e[2];
                    $start = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year);
                    $end = mktime(23, 59, 59, $month, $day, $year);
                    $this->db->where(array('created >'=> $start, 'created <'=> $end));

                }
                $query = $this->db->get($this->_table);
            } else {
                $query = $this->db->get($this->_table);
            }
            $ret = $query->result_array();
            foreach ($ret as $key => $value) {
                $ret[$key]['order_id'] = $value['id'];
            }
            return (isset($ret) && !empty($ret)) ? $ret : false;
        }
```

if you want to use get_where then pass all condition in array

```
$this->db->get_where('mytable', array('id' => $id, 'created' => $cre), $limit, $offset);
```

also you can write a sql query like:-

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM example WHERE payment_status = '0' AND intial_pay_status = '1'";

        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
          foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            //echo '<pre>'; print_r($row); 
                  }
                }
```

Comment: the `get_where` is there with a purposel so that can't change;

Comment: then pass $this->db->get_where('mytable', array('id' => $id), $limit, $offset);

Comment: i have multiple fields not only `id` and i don't know the `limit` and `offset`

Comment: then pass all field as array like where in above code

Comment: the `created` field is stored as a `timestamp` value in the `db` and I use a `date picker` to select the `day/month/year` and then I create the `24 hour` time interval, so i cant just use a `array` like that

Comment: I don't know how to do that query; The method has to remain the same, because it is being used by others;

Comment: please check my updated answer for simple query write

Comment: i did checked and tryed it; no results